# Can App Passwords For Two-Factor Authentication Be Used for More than One Device?

Tags: email, security

Hi I recently set up my Microsoft account with two-factor authentication. It made me wonder when I used an app password for Outlook - can the app password be used for more than one device? Say a "hacker" put a trojan on my computer and saw the app password when it was generated... would that app password be limited to use on one device only, in my case only on the Outlook install on my computer and not also for some nefarious use by the degenerate scum? Does it depend on the implementation say Google vs Microsoft vs anybody else?
Thanks!

Comment: @Ramhound you can create more than one app passwords, so it is up to the user on how they wish to use it.

Comment: @LPChip looks like ramhound deleted his comment. Are those app password locked down to one device or can they be reused for multiple devices?

Comment: You create an app password, and that basically becomes a password that you can use one or more times. You revoke the app password, and all connected devices stop working.

Comment: I think so... I know it is like this for google, but almost sure its also for MS.